# How to select data from database ordered ascending use two columns as criterias in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have project that using data from database. The data is ordered by using two columns like this

Here is my code, but it is not working correctly.

```
Select 
    DeviceID, Sure, MDateTime 
from 
    TblMessage 
Where 
    Sure < 200  
Order by 
    MDateTime, DeviceID asc
```

For example:

- MDatetime value is 1,2,3,5,1,3,1,9,4,4,8 etc and
- DeviceID Value  is 5,5,5,3,6,6,7,7,7,8,8 etc .

I want to order this table as this:

```
MDatetime :5,1,2,3,1,3,1,4,9,4,8
DeviceID  :3,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks marc_s for  help to edit question

Answer (score 1):

Try ordering by `DeviceID` first, then by `MDateTime`.
Further, I'd suggest not using `asc` at one column (because it is the default). Use it on both or none of the columns to avoid confusion.

```
Select 
    DeviceID, Sure, MDateTime 
from 
    TblMessage 
Where 
    Sure < 200  
Order by 
    DeviceID, MDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

ORDER BY deviceID asc, MDateTime

Comment: your code is running correctly but I have another problem .The problem is column Sure datatype . Datatype of sure is nvarchar(50) , but I need to convert to float then run code . Howq can I do .

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DeviceID,Sure,MDateTime from TblMessage Where Sure<200 ORDER BY DeviceID,MDateTime ASC
```

Comment: You need explain your answer, otherwise its likely to be ignored or deleted and unlikely to be upvoted.